# Which contract(s) are exceeding block gas limit? (truffle.js)

Tags: solidity, truffle, gas, gas-limit

Similar to [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/21262/truffle-deployment-on-test-network-says-error-exceeds-block-gas-limit), I am trying to debug a setup that is exceeding the default gas limit since upgrading to [Truffle 4](https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases).

Turning on the newly disabled (by default) optimizer seems to be a commonly suggested solution that commonly does not work (as in my case). I tried increasing the `gasLimit` in my `truffle.js` file and the contracts indeed compiled and passed their tests as they did with Truffle 3.

I want to find out which contract or contracts are too large and therefore need to be refactored to pass the default gas limits. The error message currently gives no indications which contract or contracts are exceeding block gas limits. Any debugging techniques would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I run into the same problem with truffle 4.0.1. After some investigation and advise from the truffle team I tried it with `truffle develop` and everything worked fine again. If you use `truffle develop` you don't need testrpc anymore. `truffle develop` has some advantages and cool features compared to testrpc.

You can find instructions about `truffle devlop` here: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v4.0.0

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! That worked well! Any idea how this would look in a `.travis.yml` file?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean  when you say you used `truffle develop`? I am trying to run the command `truffle migrate` and I get the out of gas error. how does `truffle develop` fix that?

Comment: You can find the instructions here: https://github.com/trufflesuite/truffle/releases/tag/v4.0.0 Scroll down to: Truffle Develop: Faster Development Cycles. If you want to migrate a contract you can start up the truffle devlop and then a kind of a shell will fire up. Inside this shell you can type migrate and your contract will be migrated. I edited my answer above and added the link to the instructions.